# Export-Csv doesn't show AD group name while exporting its members

Tags: powershell

I have a list with AD groups in a CSV file: `Input_ADGroup.csv` 
Column A looks like this:

```
CN  
ADgroup1  
ADgroup2
```

I already have some code which list all the users of the groups in the output.csv file, however I am missing the ADgroup name. So it is unclear which users are member of which group.

```
$Manager = @{Name = "Manager"; Expression = {%{(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties DisplayName).DisplayName}}}
$Manager_Location = @{Name = "Manager_Location"; Expression = {%{(Get-ADUser $_.Manager -Properties Office).Office}}}
$Fields = @(
'SamAccountName'
'CN'
'DisplayName'
'Office'
'mail'
'Department'
$Manager
$Manager_Location
)

Import-Csv -Path H:\Test\Input_ADGroup.csv | 
ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADGroup -Filter "CN -eq '$($_.CN)'" -Properties * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser -properties * | Select $Fields
} | Export-Csv -Path H:\Test\Output_ADGroup.csv -NoTypeInformation
H:\Test\Output_ADGroup.csv
```

So is it possible to get a column which shows the "source-ADgroup"... or another format which breaks the list with the ADGroup name or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO my other suggested solution is more efficient applyig the same CN from the input:

```
$Data = ForEach($CN in (Import-Csv -Path H:\Test\Input_ADGroup.csv).CN) {
   Get-ADGroup -Filter "CN -eq '$CN'" -Properties CN -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
      Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser -Properties * | Select-Object ($Fields+@{n="Group";e={$CN}})
}
$Data
$Data | Export-Csv -Path H:\Test\Output_ADGroup.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Great, this works even better because it now only shows the groupname (without OU=...etc).
 2 Questions: 1: Why/what makes it more efficient?
2: Is there a reason to run $Data twice in the bottom 2 lines?  But thanks anyway :-)

Comment: The better efficiency **is** applying CN from input without further effort. 1st `$Data` is for output to display, 2nd for storage.

Answer (score 0):

As you already have AD group name in `$_`, you can add one more calculated property to your `Select-Object` by changing this:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter "CN -eq '$($_.CN)'" -Properties * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser -properties * | Select $Fields
```

to this (saving first group name to variable to not mix up with `$_` used later in pipeline):

```
$GroupName = $_.CN

Get-ADGroup -Filter "CN -eq '$($_.CN)'" -Properties * -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser -properties * | Select ($Fields+@{n="Group";e={$GroupName}})
```

*Credits to @LotPings and @Maikel for pointing out the issue with incorrect `$_` usage in comments*

---

NOTE: remember about brackets, otherwise you'd receive an error like:

> Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument n="Group";e={$GroupName}

Comment: Hi Robdy,
Unfortunately the $_.CN you mention probably points to the CN in the Get-ADUser part: It shows the users CN instead of the Group CN.

Comment: But at the last pipeline stage, wouldn't  `$_.CN` refer to an ADUser property? So either use a `-Pipelinevariable` or change the `ForEach-Object` to a foreach ($item in Import-csv...)

Comment: @LotPings you're right, I was reproducing it on my side and apparently I wasn't 100% strict in that. Already addressed.

Comment: @Maikel - you're right, I edited my answer to address that issue

Comment: @LotPings and @robdy - The following did the trick: `Get-ADGroup -Filter "CN -eq '$($_.CN)'" -Properties CN -PipelineVariable name` and `Select ($Fields+@{n="Group";e={$name}})`. So thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

@Lotpings @robdy - Thanks for your input, I got it working so many thanks. See code below

```
Import-Csv -Path H:\Test\Input_ADGroup.csv | 
ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADGroup -Filter "CN -eq '$($_.CN)'" -Properties CN -PipelineVariable name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser -properties * | Select ($Fields+@{n="Group";e={$name}})
} | Export-Csv -Path H:\Test\Output_ADGroup.csv -NoTypeInformation
H:\Test\Output_ADGroup.csv
```

One last note: The AD group gets displayed as CN=Groupname,OU=...OU=… etc
I couldn't get it to show just "Groupname" but this really is not an issue.

Comment: `Select ($Fields+@{n="Group";e={$name.name}})` will give the group name